# gRPC for .Net CORE - how to convert C# [DataContract] classes into messages of .proto file

Tags: .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

We have an existing .Net system under WCF which we need to convert to gRPC under .Net CORE. One challenge I am facing now it to convert all our entity classes (the [DataContract] classes that will be shared between client and server side) to messages of .proto files. The problem here is that the number of those classes is huge, and a lot of them are quite complex. I can't imagine that we have to convert them manually one by one. So my question is - what's the best way to convert them? is there any tools available? or, is it a good idea to convert them at all? If not, what's best way to handle those classes.

Comment: Microsoft has a [guide for migrating from WCF to gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/migrate-wcf-to-grpc) that might help. There are plenty more if you search `migrate wcf to grpc`.

Comment: Yes, I did read the guide, but the example used in the article is really simple and needed only simple manual conversion. In our case, unfortunately, it's almost impossible to do it that way.

Comment: [This guide](https://martinbjorkstrom.com/posts/2020-09-09-migrating-wcf-to-grpc) mentions using [protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/) which looks like less work. Some changes to your `DataContract`s and some filler code between your existing WCF contract and a new ASP.NET contract using gRPC.

Comment: Thanks @Dakota Methvin. This is interesting. Sounds like you can reuse DataContract classes defined in WCF (with minimal changes) without creating .proto files. I am going to try it and see how it actually work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dakota Methvin meanwhile, if you could move your last comment into an answer, I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This guide](https://martinbjorkstrom.com/posts/2020-09-09-migrating-wcf-to-grpc) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210103201023/https://martinbjorkstrom.com/posts/2020-09-09-migrating-wcf-to-grpc)) mentions using [protobuf-net.Grpc](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101071944/https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/)) which looks like less work.

It involves some changes to your `DataContract`s and some filler code between your existing WCF contract and a new ASP.NET contract using gRPC.